# Powershell script to identify oldest file in dir and notify of age

Tags: powershell, timestamp, notify

This really should be more simple, but I've been getting goofy values.
What I want is simple. Primarily, I want powershell to send an email if the files in a folder exceed a certain age.  This part technically works.  But the script has been flaky.  And in reality, I'd also like the email to indicate how old the file is (although formatted in a simple xx minutes old)

Originally I was using something like this

```
 Get-ChildItem -path $queuepath -Recurse |
 Foreach-Object { 
  #write-host $_.fullname
  $dtdiff = New-TimeSpan ($_.CreationTime) $(Get-Date)

  if ($dtdiff.minutes -gt 120){ .....send an email stuff....
```

Trouble was, it seemed that it wasn't running that last command against all items.  As in if there were files newer than 120 minutes, it would often not trigger the email, even if there were older files..  But really, I feel like it would be simpler to fix the language to simply target the oldest file in the folder to run the rest of the command against.  (And produce a clean variable of "X minutes old"  that I can toss into the email.

Hopefully that makes sense.  And thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Don't send one email per file; collect all the files, filter that list down, then send the full list in one email. The following will give you a variable (`$NewFiles`) which contains all of the files more than 120 minutes old and their age in minutes. You can then test to make sure it's not `$null` and format it as needed for your email.

```
$NewFiles = get-childitem -recurse -file -path $queuepath |
    Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).AddMinutes(120)}|
    Select-Object -Property FullName,@{name="Age";expression={New-TimeSpan -start $_.creationtime -end $(get-date) | select-object -expandproperty minutes}};
```

Linebreaks for better formatting here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get the list of files, sort it, grab the first, and grab the last file?  Isn't that all you need to know?  I'm not clear if you really need an email for each file.

```
$Files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $queuepath -Recurse | 
   Sort-Object -Property CreationTime);
$OldestFile = $Files[0];
$NewestFile = $Files[-1];    
$Now = Get-Date;

$AgeOfNewestFile = New-TimeSpan -Start ($NewestFile.CreationTime) -End $Now;
$AgeOfOldestFile = New-TimeSpan -Start ($OldestFile.CreationTime) -End $Now;

If ($AgeOfNewestFile.TotalMinutes -gt 120) {
    Send-MailMessage -Body "File '$($OldestFile.FullName)' is $($AgeOfOldestFile.TotalMinutes) minutes old, and no file is newer than 120 minutes." [....];
}
```

You may want to include the `-File` option on `Get-ChildItem` if you don't want to include folders in your processing.  You have the `-Recurse` option specified and aren't otherwise filtering folders.

Also, you'll want to use `TotalMinutes`, not `Minutes`.  `TotalMinutes` includes the hours, days, years, etc.  `Minutes` is *just* the minutes, so it will never be greater than 59.  If the file is 3 hours and 10 minutes old, `Minutes` will be `10`, but `TotalMinutes` will be `190`.

---

If you want better formatting of the message, you can use the format operator and [composite formatting](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/16/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-and-custom-time-span-format-strings.aspx) something like this:

```
$Body = "File '{0}' is {1:dd} days, {1:hh} hours, and {1:mm} minutes old." -f $OldestFile.FullName, $AgeOfOldestFile;
```

Or like so, if you want a more fixed string:

```
$Body = "File '{0}' has an age of {1:c}." -f $OldestFile.FullName, $AgeOfOldestFile;
```

That prints the timespan in a format of [-]d.hh:mm:ss.[fffffff].

If you want to be picky, then you get to do stuff like:

```
$Body = "File '{0}' is" -f $OldestFile.FullName;
If ($AgeOfOldestFile.TotalDays -gt 0) {
    $Body += " {0:dd} day(s)," -f $AgeOfOldestFile;
}
```

And so on.

You don't have to use the format operator.  You can use embedded subexpressions.  I just did because it makes it a bit easier to read.  Well, it is when you understand what the format operator is doing.

Comment: I am guessing that the Minutes/TotalMinutes property difference was the source of confusion.

Comment: Yep.  That was it precisely.  Totally didn't realize the minutes property was limited to that.
With that in mind, you gave me what I was looking for,  I actually wasn't concerned about the newest file.  I just wanted to make sure it targeted the oldest file for that time estimate, which you gave me.

With that in mind, the total minutes property also gives decimals and looks like a bit much.  I know it's a bit overly picky.  I realize the alternative would be to include the properties for days and hours for cleanliness.

Comment: If I am feeling overly picky, and it may not be worth the time, I am still fresh behind the ears on this stuff - The best way to display it like this - 
x days, x hours, and x minutes.  Which just using the days and hours property does,  but not to bother displaying x days or x hours if the value is zero (That part I am not clear on)
That make sense.

Comment: @DavidT Well for the comparison to know if the file is older than 120 minutes you'd need to use the TotalMinutes, but otherwise you can do formatting however you want.  See my addition.

Comment: As a follow up thanks for your help!  I would vote it up, but it won't let me yet.. haha.

That gave me everything I needed.  I went a little nuts for my perfectly clean email and added "if" statements to give a value and text to a variable only if it wasn't null.  So it reads x days, x hours, and X minutes.  Unless it was only minutes, in which case it would only say x minutes.  A bit unnecessary, but I want to leave as little confusion as possible to the people being notified.